# how to abort a spring batch job if any chunk fails

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I have a spring batch application which reads the data from master table and moves all the records which are older that 90 days to an archive table.

the application context file is as 
    "

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:batch.properties" />

<context:component-scan base-package="com.prax.batch" />

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" >
    <property name="url" value="${batch.jdbc.url}"/>
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${batch.jdbc.driver}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${batch.jdbc.user}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${batch.jdbc.password}"/>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>

<bean id="jobReposotoryTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.ResourcelessTransactionManager"/>

<bean id="jobLauncher" class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher">
    <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository"></property>
</bean>

<!-- <jdbc:initialize-database data-source="dataSource">
    <jdbc:script location="${batch.schema.script}" />
</jdbc:initialize-database> -->

<!-- <batch:job-repository id="jobRepository" transaction-manager="jobReposotoryTransactionManager"></batch:job-repository> -->

<bean id="jobRepository" class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean" >
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="jobReposotoryTransactionManager"/>
</bean>

<import resource="classpath:/META-INF/spring/module-context.xml" />



</beans>
```

and  job context file is as

```
<batch:job id="fqtvArchiveJob">
    <batch:step id="readWriteDeleteStep">
        <batch:tasklet transaction-manager="transactionManager"
            start-limit="10">
            <batch:chunk reader="fqtvreader" writer="fqtvcompositewriter"
                commit-interval="1000" />
        </batch:tasklet>
    </batch:step>
</batch:job>


<bean id="fqtvreader"
    class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcCursorItemReader">
    <property name="rowMapper" ref="fqtvrowmapper" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="sql" value="${batch.reader.sql}" />
    <property name="maxRows" value="0"/>
    <property name="fetchSize" value="0" />
</bean>

<bean id="fqtvinsertwriter"
    class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcBatchItemWriter">
    <property name="assertUpdates" value="true" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="itemPreparedStatementSetter" ref="fqtvpreparedstatementsetter" />
    <property name="sql" value="${batch.writer.insert.sql}" />
</bean>

<bean id="fqtvdeletewriter"
    class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcBatchItemWriter">
    <property name="assertUpdates" value="true" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="itemPreparedStatementSetter" ref="deletestatementsetter" />
    <property name="sql" value="${batch.writer.delete.sql}" />
</bean>

<bean id="fqtvcompositewriter"
    class="org.springframework.batch.item.support.CompositeItemWriter">
    <property name="delegates">
        <list>
            <ref local="fqtvinsertwriter"/>
            <ref local="fqtvdeletewriter"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="fqtvrowmapper" class="com.prax.job.util.FqtvRowMapper"          />

<bean id="fqtvpreparedstatementsetter"
    class="com.prax.job.util.FqtvPreparedStatementSetter" />

<bean id="deletestatementsetter"
    class="com.prax.job.util.FqtvDeleteStatementSetter" />

</beans>
```

I have the requirement that if archiving of any item fails, the batch should stop and not archive any more record and send the mail notification to the users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <batch:job id="fqtvArchiveJob">
  <batch:step id="readWriteDeleteStep">
     <batch:tasklet transaction-manager="transactionManager"
        start-limit="10">
        <batch:chunk reader="fqtvreader" writer="fqtvcompositewriter"
            commit-interval="1000" skip-limit="10" >
        <skippable-exception-classes>
            <exclude class="customExceptionIDontWannaSkip"/>
        </skippable-exception-classes>
       </batch:chunk>
   </batch:tasklet>
 </batch:step>
  <batch:listeners>
                <batch:listener ref="jobListener" />
  </batch:listeners>
</batch:job>
```

And `JobListener` should implements `JobExecutionListener` and override :

```
@Override
public void afterJob(JobExecution exec) {
  BatchStatus status = exec.getStatus();
  if (!status.equals(BatchStatus.COMPLETED)){
   //send the mail
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for providing help. here skip limit is defined as 10. But the requirement is that if batch is not able to process any record then it should stop instead of skipping that record and should send the mail notification then and there.

Comment: the process is no able to process any record == > Not skippable exception. if you dont wanna skip any exception `<exclude class="java.lang.Exception"/>`, as for skip limit you can set it the way you want